# The emulator process for AVD Pixel_5_API_30 has terminated

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have been gettting The emulator process for AVD Pixel_5_API_30 has terminated as an error response trying to open to my emulator how do I fix it?

I was expecting the emulator to popup after I tried creating a new virtual device

Answer (score 2):

go to C:\Users\yourusername.android  folder and see if there is advancedFeatures.ini,

if no , just create new txt and then finally save as advancedFeatures.ini in ANSI(not UTF-8).
content as below:
==copy below==

```
# Here's how to disable Vulkan apps to talk to the emulator.

# Add the following lines to ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini (create this file if it doesn't exist already):

Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on


advancedFeatures
```

==paste above==

I watch youtube video and this works for API 30 . However, it doesn't work for API 31.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the 3 dots then click on wipe data. Worked for me.

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaKTT.png)

Answer (score 0):

2 case first if you have only one virtual device click on the 3 dots and wipe the data and if you have more then one device delete the other and try wiping the data of one which you want to use

Answer (score 0):

Wipe Data and cold boot didn't work for me. so I deleted the emulator and created a new device with the same configuration worked fine