# Android Studio: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_6_API 30 has terminated

Tags: windows, android-studio, emulation

I'm a newbie to Android Studio and I install Android Studio 2021.1.1 from scratch on Windows 10, but when I want to run the emulator, it just can't be launched with this error:

[image]

in the log located at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.1\log, I got some info as below. So can anyone help to figure it out?

```
    2022-03-24 16:09:10,973 [ 826150]   INFO - testKnownPluginVersionProvider - 'gradle' plugin missing from the offline Maven repo, will use default 7.1.2 
2022-03-24 16:09:11,368 [ 826545]   INFO - ativeWorkspaceModificationTask - NDK support for project 'Demo1' is disabled because the project doesn't contain any valid native configurations. 
2022-03-24 16:09:27,095 [ 842272]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Error setting permissions for C:\Users\xxx\temp\emu.tmp 
2022-03-24 16:09:29,433 [ 844610]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -studio-params C:\Users\xxx\temp\emu.tmp -avd Nexus_6_API_30 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300 
2022-03-24 16:09:39,317 [ 854494]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: WARNING | Crash service did not start 
2022-03-24 16:09:39,317 [ 854494]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator:  
2022-03-24 16:09:39,471 [ 854648]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator. 
2022-03-24 16:09:45,515 [ 860692]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.9.0 (build_id 8316981) (CL:N/A) 
2022-03-24 16:09:45,515 [ 860692]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) 
2022-03-24 16:09:45,515 [ 860692]   WARN - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741819 
2022-03-24 16:09:55,157 [ 870334]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.pluginsAdvertisement.PluginAdvertiserExtensionsStateService$State 
2022-03-24 16:09:55,188 [ 870365]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appClangTidySettings took 16 ms, FileTypeManager took 15 ms, PluginFeatureService took 15 ms, VcsApplicationSettings took 16 ms 
2022-03-24 16:09:55,701 [ 870878]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=Demo1, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=C:\N-20L6PF1KPTJU-Data\xxx\Documents\99.Self.Learning\00.Android)XDebuggerManager took 30 ms
```

For the permission under C:\Users\xxx\temp*, it has no difference if I set it to full-control or read-only.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emulator: Unexpected feature list: MultiDisplay VulkanNullOptionalStrings YUV420888toNV21 YUVCache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57424137/emulator-unexpected-feature-list-multidisplay-vulkannulloptionalstrings-yuv420)

Comment: @Julia, this is not the same error. Thanks anyway

Comment: Did you try the solution mentioned there?

Comment: I have posted a answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71580441/the-emulator-process-for-avd-pixel-5-api-30-has-terminated/71628945#71628945 I am not sure if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what's the rc, but when I tried Nexus 6 API 28, it works.